# Make an Image as a button

Tags: html, css, image, button

Well I wanna make an image as a button .

this is my code :

```
<input type="image" name"lvl1_1" style="border:1px dotted #000000;" class="main" width="50" src="images/main/lvl1/1.png">
```

This code doesn't work probaply , if I change the type from 'image' to 'submit' it works but the image and the effects disappear .

I don't really see a problem in the code :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to submit a form, you can create a submit button, then set the image for the button as a background image using CSS.

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name"lvl1_1" style="border:1px dotted #000000;" class="main" width="50" >
```

CSS:

```
.main {
background-image: url("images/main/lvl1/1.png");
background-position:  0px 0px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: That's goood .. Thnx 4 help

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways of doing so:

1. Add an **OnClick**="*whatever the image button is supposed to do*" attribute to the input type **image**.
2. Take the input type to be **button** instead of image and use the **background**="*image source*" attribute on it.
3. You can use the type **image-set** and give coordinates of the area you want to make clickable.